# Prove that $U$ Is a subspace of $M^\mathbb{R}_{n\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra

$$U = \left \{ \left (\begin{matrix} a & b & c\\ b & c & b\\ c & b & a\end{matrix} \right )\mid a,b,c\in \mathbb{R} \right \}$$

How do I prove that this is a subspace?

It's not subspace by definition?

Comment: Why would it be a subspace “by definition”? What are you using for your definition of a subspace?

Answer (score 4):

It's a sub*set* of $M_3(\mathbb{R})$ by definition, but a sub*space* is a subset with some additional properties - namely, nonemptiness, closure under vector addition, and closure under scalar multiplication.

For instance, the set of matrices in $M_3(\mathbb{R})$ whose top-left entry is $2$ is *not* a subspace, since it's not closed under addition *or* multiplication.

So you have to check that $U$ satisfies all the properties a subspace needs to.

- Is $U$ nonempty? (This is easy.)
- If $A, B\in U$, is $A+B\in U$?
- If $A\in U$ and $r\in\mathbb{R}$, is $rA\in U$?

Answer (score 2):

It is, but you have to check that the definition is indeed verified. You can write that 
$$U=\mathrm{span}\Big(\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}\Big),$$ which is I think your idea.